# ImportError: No module named 'selenium'(Selenium is there)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a script with **python 3.5** on windows 10 and i got this error

```
File "auto_login.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I install selenium with `pip` but still i got this error.Is there something else i forgot to do it?

Comment: Do you have multiversions of python? Maybe you did a `pip install` on python 2.6

Comment: I have also 2.7 but i installed it on 3.5,I also checked the folders in appdata